# Filling a grid with irregular shapes

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking to build an algorithm to determine how many distinct ways there are to fill a 6x10 grid with 12 specific tetris like pieces.

All pieces consist of five blocks each, and can be mirrored and rotated freely. They must all fit into the grid (without overlap), and no spaces should be left over.

Additionally, an arrangement is only considered distinct, if it isn't a mirroring or rotated image of a previously existing arrangement.

I've chosen to give each rotation step it's own matrix, and the representation of the T-Block would look like this:

```
[
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
],
[
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
],
[
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
],
[
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
]
```

My initial approach was brute force; trying every single starting point with one shape, and then trying to fit all the other pieces around it one by one, starting from the top left corner.

However, I am curious if anyone has a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you done research on pentominos?

Because thats where I start- I type that word on to the search engine and start.

Your shapes are not irregular they are regular by the utmost degree.

If you find a little paper Donald E. Knuth. "Dancing links" (Postscript, 1.6 megabytes). Includes a summary of Scott's and Fletcher's articles. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino)

he says that he has developed some programs - maybe you can convert those to java. Then you can present it here and we can start talking because this is mainly a programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in general you can only do brute force, unless you have some specific case (e.g. all pieces are 2x2 cubes). You can use some tricks though:

- if there is only one "S" shape, you can without loss of generality assume it is in the upper left quadrant, and multiply the result by 4, plus maybe some cases for it being on the axis;
- "pick up a tile and try all positions recursively" may perform differently than "pick up the first available position and try all possible tile fits that cover it";
- if there's a hole of a size not divisible by 4, you can break;
- if there's a hole, you may split the computation (number of ways to fill everything = number of ways to fill the hole * number of ways to fill the rest);

and maybe some more.